# std::function template syntax

Tags: c++11, lambda, std-function

I am fimilar with std::function , but i am reading a book that there is a code like this :

```
template<typename GameObject, typename Function>
std::function<void(SceneNode&, sf::Time)> derivedAction(Function fn)
{
    return [=](SceneNode& node, sf::Time dt)
    {
        assert(dynamic_cast<GameObject *>(&node) != nullptr);

        fn(static_cast<GameObject *>(&node), dt)
    }
}
```

then the book use template like this :

```
Command moveLeft;//command is a structure
moveLeft.action//action is a std::function object 
= derivedAction<Aircraft>(AircraftMover(-playerSpeed, 0));
//derivedAction specify<Aircraft> ???
```

my questions are :

1-derivedAction must be an object of std::function , i have checked references but i haven't found this kind of initialazation with {} , how this works ?

2-it is complicated to me , to understand the lambda expression , and why there is a return for it ?

i am pretty confused about this peice of code , any explination would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is a wrapper around anything, that can be called (i.e, you can use `operator()` on it). That is pointer to a function, class having `operator()` overloaded or lambda expression.

In your case, `derivedAction` is a templated function, accepting a single parameter (of templated type of name `Function`) and returning a function having `void` return type and accepting two parameters -- `SceneNode&` and `sf::Time`.

So to answer your questions.

> 1-derivedAction must be an object of std::function , i have checked references but i haven't found this kind of initialazation with {} , how this works ?

No, `derivedAction` is a function itself, like any other (i.e. `int foo(){ return 0; }`).

> 2-it is complicated to me , to understand the lambda expression , and why there is a return for it ?

Once again, the return value of `derivedAction` is a function (or rahter, something, which is callable).

If you look closely to the code of `derivedAction`, you will see, that it only wraps a function `Function fn` with some checks.

Comment: one other question : if Gameobject typename was before Function typename , and we used same syntax when we call derivedAction , we would have a compile error ?

Comment: so the derived function return the entire lambda expression as a std::function ?

Comment: @shayan If you would switch those two `typename`s, it would not cause compiler error in definition. It would however, produce compiler error at call to `derivedAction`, becuse [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) will fail.

Comment: @shayan Yes, `derivedAction`'s return *value*, is that lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, derivedAction is a function, so you could define an empty body `{}` just like with any other function.

As for your second question, the `return` is the return of `derivedAction`. The breakdown of the lambda is as follows:

- `[=]` Instructs to capture any referenced variable by making a copy
- `(SceneNode& node, sf::Time dt)` describes the input arguments of the lambda function
- In the body of the lambda, the lambda function operates on fn(). It casts `node` to a different type and modifies the `node` object.

In your example, `fn` is `AircraftMover(-playerSpeed, 0)`. playerSpeed is of type `SceneNode&`, and 0 is of type `sf::Time`. The return type of that function is `void`. So, what all of this does in the end is modify the `playerSpeed` you feed into it based on `dt`. Hope this makes sense..!